# How to convert [(Data.Text.Internal.Text,Data.Text.Internal.Text)] -> Text

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I make a weather program whose essence is very simple: the user enters the language in which the program will work, the city and date, and then I check it all. But when the user enters the correct city but with a small letter, the program gives an error, although the city is entered correctly

I now about `toLower` function, but i can't use it because of i get a pair of cities in type `[(Text,Text)]`

```
    let pairsOfCityNames  = [ let names = T.splitOn (",") twoNames
                                    [nameForHuman, nameForServer] = L.filter (not . T.null) (names)
                               in (nameForHuman, nameForServer)
                             | twoNames <- cityNames 
                             ]
          (allNamesForHumans, _) = unzip pairsOfCityNames
```

And i get something like:

```
[ ("Aragatsotn", "Aragatsotn")
, ("Ararat", "Ararat")
, ("Armavir", "Armavir")
, ("Dilijan", "Dilijan")
, ("Gegharkunik", "Gegharkunik")
, ("Gyumri", "Gyumri")
, ("Kotayk", "Kotayk")
, ("Shirak", "Shirak")
, ("Syunik", "Syunik")
, ("Vanadzor", "Vanadzor")
, ("Yerevan", "Yerevan")
]
```

I want when the user enters the correct city but with a small letter, the program works

And how i check it:

```
  cityFromUser <- TIO.getLine
  let lovercaseForCity = T.toLower cityFromUser
  cityNameForServer <- case L.lookup lovercaseForCity pairsOfCityNames of 
        Nothing -> do
            TIO.putStrLn $ messageErrorWrongCity phrasesForUser
            exitFailure 
        Just cityNameForServer -> return cityNameForServer
    TIO.putStrLn cityNameForServer
```

Comment: This looks basically as a *map/dictionary* if I understand it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this list of pairs is meant to convert `"ararat"` into `"Ararat"` to compensate for the user's lack of Title Case, while the server you communicate with only accepts one capitalisation of a given city name.

But I could be wrong in this understanding.

You could use [`Data.Text.toTitle`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text/docs/Data-Text.html#v:toTitle):

```hs
do cityFromUser <- T.toTitle <$> TIO.getLine
   ...
```

Since you're dealing with input sanitation, you may also want to [`T.strip`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text/docs/Data-Text.html#v:strip) leading and trailing whitespace from what the user entered. With `T.toTitle` you could instead of a list of pairs use a [`Data.Set`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Set.html) of valid city names for the server:

```hs
import           Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set

type CityName = Text

validCityNames :: Set CityName
validCityNames = Set.fromList
  [ "Aragatsotn"
  , "Ararat"
  , "Armavir"
  , "Dilijan"
  , "Gegharkunik"
  , "Gyumri"
  , "Kotayk"
  , "Shirak"
  , "Syunik"
  , "Vanadzor"
  , "Yerevan"
  , ...
  ]

getValidCityNameFromUser :: IO (Maybe CityName)
getValidCityNameFromUser = do
  cityNameFromUser <- T.toTitle . T.strip <$> TIO.getLine
  if Set.member cityNameFromUser validCityNames
    then return (Just cityNameFromUser)
    else do
      TIO.putStrLn $ messageErrorWrongCity phrasesForUser
      exitFailure
```